# Flutter - How to add Firebase-Auth user credentials to new records (FireStore documents)?

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a simple Crud app with Flutter and Firebase which the records (documents created in FireStore) are related to the user who has been Authenticated. Therefore the Crud functions will only be performed by the user who created the record. IE a user will only be able able to edit/update/delete the records they added in the first place.

I have the firebase_auth and crud functions working nicely with firestore. the issues i'm have is with relating the two. I have chosen to use the users email and the unique identifier (i'm not sure if it's better to use the auto generated user id or not). I have created a separate function for simply returning the current user's email as it's being added to the firestore document. The problem is the first time i add a record the user email returns *null*, If i submit the form again it starts working fine.

```
String _userEmail;
_getUserAuthEmail() {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
    setState((){this._userEmail = user.email;}); 
  });
  return this._userEmail;
}
```

Which is being called from the onPressed event

```
onPressed: () {
  crudObj.addData({
    'itemName': this.itemName,
    'userEmail': _getUserAuthEmail(),
  }).then((result) {
    dialogTrigger(context);
  }).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
  });
},
```

As i'm just starting out please let me know if there is a better approach. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting null because you are not waiting for the currentUser method to settle. Change the _getUserEmail method like this:

```
String _userEmail;
_getUserAuthEmail() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  setState(() {
      _userEmail = user.email;
    });
  return this._userEmail;
}
```

Also, about this
"I have chosen to use the users email and the unique identifier (i'm not sure if it's better to use the auto generated user id or not)."

I suggest you using the user's uid for saving user related stuff.

Comment: you are right. From a data protection standpoint (important nowadays) one should only store the UID in the DB and leave the email at Firebase Auth.